# Rebuild vcpkg without installing again

Tags: visual-studio, vcpkg, shogun

I have installed a vcpkg package with `vcpkg install shogun:x64-windows`. The build fails and I need to change a file to fix it.
How can I rebuild the package without the `install` option, that overwrites my changes?
I cannot find any VC project in the `vcpkg\buildtrees\shogun\x64-windows-<configuration>\src\shogun` folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should:

1. delete buildtrees directory
2. Execute command "vcpkg remove shogun:x64-windows"
3. If you need to change shogun solution before install you should write a .patch file and copy to this path("(install_path)\vcpkg\ports\shogun")
4. Add your patch file to "(install_path)\vcpkg\ports\shogun\portfile.cmake"
5. Find this line "set(ABSEIL_PATCHES" and add your patch file name in next line
6. Then "vcpkg install shogun:x64-windows"