# vcpkg how to edit package file when compilation fails when installing package?

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, package-managers, vcpkg

I'm installing dependencies for some project which downloads dependencies with `vcpkg` (the project is Hyperledger Iroha, but it does not matter). Unfortunately when compiling dependencies with my compiler (g++ 12.1.0) one of packages (abseil) is not compiling.

The reason why it is not compiling is easy to fix in code - just one line to change.

The line is pointed by `cmake`:

```
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:146 (message):
    Command failed: /usr/bin/cmake --build . --config Debug --target install -- -v -j13
    Working Directory: /home/agh/Pulpit/blockchain/internship2022/iroha/vcpkg-build/buildtrees/abseil/x64-linux-dbg
    See logs for more information:
      /home/agh/Pulpit/blockchain/internship2022/iroha/vcpkg-build/buildtrees/abseil/install-x64-linux-dbg-out.log
```

and the error is:

```
/home/agh/Pulpit/blockchain/internship2022/iroha/vcpkg-build/buildtrees/abseil/src/ca9688e9f6-e4cda1d679.clean/absl/debugging/failure_signal_handler.cc:139:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘max(long int, int)’
  139 |   size_t stack_size = (std::max(SIGSTKSZ, 65536) + page_mask) & ~page_mask;
      |                        ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/algorithm:60,
```

The reason is easy to fix - I just need to change one line to fix this.
Unfortunately when I'm changing the line of code and then after rerunning:

```
vcpkg install abseil
```

my changes are being removed before compilation. I found option which should help:
`--editable`, but it is happening again.

I would like to ask what is more professional (but still fast) way to change files, which are being build with `vcpkg` and containing errors?

---

The one solution which I found is that I can edit package:
`-- Using cached /home/agh/Pulpit/blockchain/internship2022/iroha/vcpkg-build/downloads/abseil-abseil-cpp-997aaf3a28308eba1b9156aa35ab7bca9688e9f6.tar.gz` 
when I edit the package I see error:

```
          File path: [ /home/agh/Pulpit/blockchain/internship2022/iroha/vcpkg-build/downloads/abseil-abseil-cpp-997aaf3a28308eba1b9156aa35ab7bca9688e9f6.tar.gz ]
      Expected hash: [ bdd80a2278eef121e8837791fdebca06e87bfff4adc438c123e0ce11efc42a8bd461edcbbe18c0eee05be2cd6100f9acf8eab3db58ac73322b5852e6ffe7c85b ]
        Actual hash: [ cf8bb1676d2fcba8bdd4bc30e2060bc5552a348d6e192561aec2763460120b10dcb86e29efe60d972d4b241783563bc8067381c48209daee4ecc429786ef6bba ]
```

so I can edit file containing the hash: `ports/abseil/portfile.cmake`

---

Another solution is to run proper `cmake` of the abseil project with `VERBOSE=1`, then copy failing build commands after that edit files and rerun commands.

---

I know that my solutions are quite dirty so I would like to know if there is cleaner way to solve problem - how to edit source code of a library when it is not compiling when we use `vcpkg` package manager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I do it:

1. Run install with `--editable`

```bash
vcpkg install abseil --editable
```

2. Initialize git repo in source dir:

```bash
cd buildtrees/abseil/src/_random_string_/
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "init"
```

3. Patch the library
4. Verify the library builds by calling install with `--editable` again

```bash
vcpkg install abseil --editable
```

5. Create patch from changes (or commits)

```
git diff > fix_build.patch
```

6. Copy patch into port dir and adjust `portfile.cmake`

```
vcpkg_from_github(
    REPO google/abseil
    ...
    PATCHES fix_build.patch # <-- this is our patch
)
```

7. Copy the port directory into your project's overlay-ports dir. -OR- Update port version, submit it into your custom registry.
8. (optional, but appreciated) Create PR in upstream and vcpkg main repo.

Answer (score 1):

Here u have more simply way. Im used for custom code changed for ffmpeg using and then build with vcpkg.

[Rebuild vcpkg without installing again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162414/rebuild-vcpkg-without-installing-again)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).